# HTML Bootstrap Carousel Control Arrows Won't Work

Tags: html, iframe, bootstrap-4, carousel

So I semi-succesfully created an Bootstrap iFrame Carousel for Google Sites. The ONLY problem I am having when loaded into the "embed" option on the new Google Sites is that the carousel control arrows do not switch to the next item, but they open a new tab with a weird URL and nothing on the page. What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<!--Carousel Wrapper-->
<div id="carousel-example-1z" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <!--Indicators-->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!--/.Indicators-->
  <!--Slides-->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <!--First slide-->
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe src="//www.flexmls.com/share/3q3RH/219-Open-Gulf-Street-Miramar-Beach-FL-32550"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/First slide-->
    <!--Second slide-->
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe src="//www.flexmls.com/share/3q3fX/3467-Scenic-Highway-98-Destin-FL-32541"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/Second slide-->
    <!--Third slide-->
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe src="//www.flexmls.com/share/3q3jy/2440-Spur-Lane-Gulf-Breeze-FL-32563"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/Third slide-->
  </div>
  <!--/.Slides-->
  <!--Controls-->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example-1z" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example-1z" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  <!--/.Controls-->
</div>
<!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change to `href="javascript:void(0)" data-target="#carousel-example-1z" ` to see if it helps